# Using RemoteRegistry for exporting resource of a tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 apim 1.10.0, I created a tenant with domain ofer.com, with admin username ofer, password admin

I'm able to login to carbon management console UI for this tenant using credentials ofer@ofer.com, password: admin.

Now I'm trying to use RemoteRegistry in order to export the tiers.xml of that tenant.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry;
    import org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryClientUtils;

    public class test {

        private static String serverHostname = "...";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "p:/main/test/wso2carbon.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",         "wso2carbon");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
            System.setProperty("carbon.repo.write.mode", "true");        

            RemoteRegistry remote_registry = new RemoteRegistry(new URL("https://" + serverHostname + ":9443/registry"), "ofer@ofer.com", "admin");

            File toFile = new File("e:/tiers.xml");
            RegistryClientUtils.exportFromRegistry( toFile, "/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml" ,remote_registry);        
        }

    }
```

When I run this code with credentials admin/admin:

```
    RemoteRegistry remote_registry = new RemoteRegistry(new URL("https://" + serverHostname + ":9443/registry"), "admin", "admin");
```

It runs successfully, but with

```
    RemoteRegistry remote_registry = new RemoteRegistry(new URL("https://" + serverHostname + ":9443/registry"), "ofer@ofer.com", "admin");
```

I get a "unatuthorized" exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to export from registry
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryClientUtils.exportFromRegistry(RegistryClientUtils.java:89)
at test.main(test.java:26)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unauthorized
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry.get(RemoteRegistry.java:174)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryClientUtils.processExport(RegistryClientUtils.java:123)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryClientUtils.exportFromRegistry(RegistryClientUtils.java:86)
... 1 more
```

Any idea what I have missed? Is there anywhere I should grant access to ofer@ofer.com to do the export?

/// EDITED ///

I see now that there is another class, RemoteRegistryService for getting a user registry. I'm trying:

```
    RemoteRegistryService registryService = new RemoteRegistryService("http://" + serverHostname + ":9763/registry", "admin", "admin");
    UserRegistry ur = registryService.getSystemRegistry(...)
```

For this to work I see that it requires a realm service. How do I get hold of that?

Answer (score 1):

Found it out.
The URL should include the tenant domain, i.e. instead of 
http://localhost:9443/registry
http://localhost:9443/t//registry

Updated code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry;
    import org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryClientUtils;

    public class test {

        private static String serverHostname = "...";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "p:/main/test/wso2carbon.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",         "wso2carbon");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
            System.setProperty("carbon.repo.write.mode", "true");        

            RemoteRegistry remote_registry = new RemoteRegistry(new URL("https://" + serverHostname + ":9443/t/ofer.com/registry"), "ofer@ofer.com", "admin");

            File toFile = new File("e:/tiers.xml");
            RegistryClientUtils.exportFromRegistry( toFile, "/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml" ,remote_registry);        
        }

    }
```